# Unexpected Operator error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

This is the shell code I am running:

```
#!bin/bash

while true
do
        req=$(curl http://localhost/devcalls/camerarequest.php)

        if [ "$req" == "1" ]
        then
                sudo bash /home/ckoy-admin/HAS_system/camera/cam.sh
        fi
done
```

and this is the error I get when I execute:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     1  100     1    0     0     56      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    58
CAM.sh: 7: [: 1: unexpected operator
```

Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: All I can think of is that there might be some invisible characters in your file.  Did you type that in with `vi`?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Show content of `echo "$req" | hexdump -C`. Check your file for special characters with `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`.

Comment: You are running your script with `sh CAM.sh`, and `sh` is a shell (probably `dash`) that doesn't recognize `==` as a valid operator with the `[` command.

Comment: @chepner.. yes, changing the `==` to `-eq` worked!

Comment: Note that `#!bin/bash` is probably not what you want, as there seems to be a missing `/`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
if [ "$req" = 1 ]
```

or even better

```
if [ "$req" -eq 1 ]
```

See the syntax and operators in [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: @phd..Adding the `-eq` instead of `==` worked.. Thank you.. :D

Comment: same for me, also had to put -ne instead of !=

Comment: If the script were actually executed by Bash, it would actually work; but the shebang is broken, so the script will have been executed by `sh` after all, which does not portably accept `==` in lieu of the correct and portable `=`. For the record, for the shebang to be valid, it needs to start with exactly the two bytes `#!` followed by the _absolute_ path to the desired interpreter (i.e. `/bin/bash`, not just `bin/bash`).

Answer (score 18):

To compare **INTEGER**

```
if [ "$req" -eq 1 ]
```

To compare **STRING**

```
if [ "$req" = "string" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `bash run.sh` instead of `sh run.sh` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

View shell:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 11 2021 /bin/sh -> dash
```

This problem occurs due to the incompatibility between dash and bash. There are two ways to solve it:

```
  (1): sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash select NO
Change the dash of ubuntu's default shell link to traditional bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 August 11 09:53 /bin/sh -> dash (before modification)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 11 09:53 /bin/sh -> bash
This problem occurs due to the incompatibility between dash and bash. .

  (2): Change == to =: because the default judgment statement in dash is =. .
For specific dash and bash, you can use man to find out. .
```

Answer (score -1):

`if [ "expr n%2 -eq 0" ]`

`if [ "expr n%2=0" ]`

or

`if [ 'expr n%2=0' ]`

`if [ 'expr n%2 -eq 0' ]`

you can use any 4 method above mentioned i have tried all other answers but including every thing inside the "" gave me the output

Comment: This is complete hallucination. The quotes turn this into a check for a non-empty string, which is true by definition.